# How do I call variable in function?

Tags: javascript

please refer to the following code,

```
var XClass = function () {
    this.dataMember = "hello world";

    $("div").on("click", "button", function() {
        console.log(this.dataMember);   //error 
    });  

}
```

How do I access this.dataMember in **on** function? I googled and new on js.

Comment: I think this is a better duplicate: [How to access the correct `this` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try by assigning `this` to a variable:

```
var XClass = function () {
    var that = this;
    this.dataMember = "hello world";

    $("div").on("click", "button", function() {
        console.log(that.dataMember); 
    });  
}
```

This way, `that` will refer to the current XClass object. Otherwise, inside a event handler callback, `this` refers to the object being clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Use `bind` to set context

```
var XClass = function () {
    this.dataMember = "hello world";

    $("div").on("click", "button", function() {
        console.log(this.dataMember);   //error 
    }.bind(this));  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign `this` to a variable:

```
var XClass = function () {
    var self = this;
    this.dataMember = "hello world";

    $("div").on("click", "button", function() {
        console.log(self.dataMember);   // no error 
    });  
}
```